# Android - R8 causes subclass of LinearLayoutManager to crash

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-r8, linearlayoutmanager

This may be more of a bug report than a question. I'm pretty sure I've found an issue with R8.  See my experiments and bug report here.  Am I doing something wrong?

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314984596